# Azure KeyChain value propagation to App Service Environment Variable

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-keyvault

I have an Azure App Service, that utilised environment variables to receive an API key.

The value of the Env Var references a Key Vault secret:

`@Microsoft.KeyVault(SecretUri=https://vault-name.vault.azure.net/secrets/secretname/)`

The problem is, when I update the keyvault secret value, this does not propagate to the App Service. It continues to use the old value. Even when restarting the App Service.

Is there a key to giving this a kick to cause the updated key to propagate to the service?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- You need to add a system assigned identity in your app service and you have to add an access policy in your key vault.
- To add system assigned identity in your app service go to `identity` tab in the portal and click on `System assigned`and then click on and click save

[image]

- Now In our key vault go under `Access policies` tab and create an access policy by clicking `create`

[image]

- Now a popup will emerge where choose the level of permission on your keys, secret etc. you will need at least one. Then in the next popup  you will have to search for the app service in the search bar select .
- Once the access policy is created you can add the key vault reference just like you added

```
@Microsoft.KeyVault(SecretUri=<URL>)
```

Your app settings will appear like this :
[image]

With secret being imported properly

Comment: Hey, Thanks for this. This is the current setup. The issue is when the key is CHANGED. The service continues to use the old one.

Comment: Try adding version of the secret in the secret URL in this format `https://vault-name.vault.azure.net/secrets/secretname/version`